# В чем разница между файлами *.jsx и *.js

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня в проекте на UI используется React/Redux, при этом какие-то файлы имеют расширение  `*.jsx`, а какие-то `*.js`, при этом `JSX` сиснтаксис используется в обоих случаях.

В каких случаях есть острая небходимость делать расширение файла `*.jsx`, если в файлах `*.js` `JSX` сиснтаксис, так же валидно обрабатывается?

Comment: JSX преобразуется в JavaScript транслятором (babel, typescript). Если у вас на проекте настроено прогонять через транслятор JS-файлы - то он спокойно оттранслирует JSX-синтаксис в JS файлах в JavaScript.

Comment: @PashaPash тоесть получается что вероятно сначала писали без транслятора, а потом добавили и начали *.js вместо *.jsx писать..? Правильно рассуждаю?

Comment: да, скорее всего шли по пути "а, нам нужен es6 во всех файлах, а не только в *.jsx. включай все подряд!". поищите у себя в конфиге транслятора - там будет явно сказано, какие плагины/лоадеры для *.js подключены